# increase maximum number of open files (ulimit)

Tags: linux, rhel, ulimit

I need to increase the files limit on my system (for running on large files in Spark).

The release of linux on my server is:

```
Redhat Release: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.6 (Maipo)
```

I added the following lines to /etc/security/limits.conf (the second and the third lines are my addition):

```
#@student        -       maxlogins       4
*        soft    nproc           64000
*        hard    nproc           64000
# End of file
```

I added the following line to /etc/pam.d/login file (second line is my addition):

```
session    required     pam_namespace.so
session    required     pam_limits.so
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke
```

I closed the session and logged in again. I typed:

ulimit -n
But got the same old result: 1024.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> *        soft    nproc           64000
> ```
>
> How can I solve it?

Well for starters you can use the correct spelling of `nofile`.  ☺